# How do I fix git duplicate folder names remotely only

Tags: git, github

I renamed folders in git locally by only change the case (ex: homepage => HomePage), so locally all looks good.
On GitHub however, the 2 folders (`homepage` and `HomePage`) are there.

To make sure my local and remote repos are in sync, I deleted my local project folder and ran `git clone` again. The duplicate folders on GitHub are *not* cloned, so it seems to me like a GitHub issue.

[image: GitHub screenshot https://i.imgur.com/yVg8cNd.png]

I want the extra folders (`homepage` and `articles`) on GitHub to go away.

Comment: I don't bear any love for GitHub, but I doubt they are failing at this. Double check your Git configurations, might be wrong at some hosts.

Comment: Potentially duplicate: Check this [link](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/424130/change-a-directory-name-in-a-github-repository-remotely-directly-from-local-lin)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> The duplicate folders on GitHub are *not* cloned, so it seems to me like a GitHub issue

No, it is a local OS issue, which is *not* case sensitive.

Try:

```
git rm -r homepage/
git checkout -- HomePage
```

Check that `HomePage` is there. Add, commit and push and see if you would still have "two" `homepage` folders.